# how to disable public ip and make the external traffic flow through the private ip of the firewall

Tags: linux, firewall, routing, linux-networking, private-ip

So, our requirement is to disable public ip of the node and then route the traffic through the private ip of the fortigate firewall.
NOTE:
eth1= public ip
eth0= private ip

so, I am following the below steps.

mv /etc/one-context.d/loc-10-network /root/.

ifdown eth0

cd /etc/network/
comment all the public ip lines and add the private ip of the firewall as the gateway to the private ip line.

route add default gw $firewall_private_ip eth1

Now, after this external connectivity is not happening,

ping google.com is giving blank response.

But the connectivity between the other server and this happening fine.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: `ip route` might be enlighting.  Look for multiple default routes and delete the wrong one.  Also, debug with `traceroute`.

Comment: Is your firewall configured to NAT private IPs?